# Unable to divide the latest freebase dump

Tags: compression, freebase

I've dividing the freebase dump into smaller compressed files using a ruby script, then with freebase-rdf-2014-10-26-00-00 it stopped working, ending prematurely. Today I wrote a java program that acts the same way as ruby. Are there changes to freebase dump regarding compression?

```
package splitfreebase;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

/**
 *
 * @author ron
 */
public class SplitFreebase {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(
                        new GZIPInputStream(
                                new FileInputStream(args[0]))));

        BufferedWriter out = null;

        long cnt = 0;
        int file_cnt = 0;

        while (in.ready()) {
            if ((cnt % 10000000) == 0) {
                String name = args[0].substring(0, args[0].length() - 3)
                        + "_" + file_cnt + ".gz";

                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
                out = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(
                                new GZIPOutputStream(
                                        new FileOutputStream(name))));
                file_cnt++;
            }

            if (out != null) {
                out.write(in.readLine());
                out.newLine();
            }

            cnt++;
        }

        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }

        in.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SplitFreebase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SplitFreebase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You don't include any information on how you're trying to split or the failure mode, but regardless, it sounds like either a question that you should ask or a bug that you should report to the Freebase team at Google.

Comment: I don't think it is a program issue. I suspect the ruby and java use the same algorithm and it breaks when files grow. 28425065218 Aug 10 14:40 freebase-rdf-2014-08-10-00-00.gz works, the latest is 29498770878 Nov  2 18:13 freebase-rdf-2014-11-02-00-00.gz

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well. Java failed and ruby did too in the exact same way. I divided the problem substituting gunzip STDIN and it works now.

Freebase file:
-rw-r--r-- 1 ron users 29498770878 Nov  2 18:13 freebase-rdf-2014-11-02-00-00.gz

```
$ gunzip -c freebase_s19.gz | ./free_sp_stdin.rb howdy_pardner
```

Here is the script. I'm not a ruby programmer, may not be elegant.

```
require 'zlib'

file_cnt = 0;
error = ""
wgz = nil

if ARGV[1] != nil
  file_cnt = ARGV[1].to_i;
end

base_name =  ARGV[0]

STDIN.each_with_index do |line, idx|

#puts idx.to_s+"  "+line

 if((idx % 100000000) == 0)
   if(idx != 0)
     wgz.close
   end

   wgz = Zlib::GzipWriter.open(base_name + file_cnt.to_s + ".gz")
   puts base_name + file_cnt.to_s + ".gz"
   file_cnt+=1
 end

 if((idx % 1000000) == 0)
  print "."
 end

error = line
wgz <<  line

end

wgz.close
puts error
```